# Issue with normal score transformation of raster data in arcpy script

Tags: arcpy, numpy, scipy, cell-statistics, memoryerror

I am writing a script as part of a larger model builder workflow to perform a normal score transformation on an inputted raster that will be used for maximum likelihood classification. The normal score transformation is based on the answer from @Sara in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420741/820534) to [Numpy transformation to normal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999669/numpy-transformation-to-normal-distribution) thread for performing the transformation on an array. This is the formula they used for their answer:

[image: van der Waerden's Normal Score Transformation Method]

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata, norm


    # Local Variables from Model Builder
    in_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    print in_raster
    name = os.path.basename(in_raster).rstrip(os.path.splitext(in_raster)[1])

    # Retreaves input raster properties
    ras_desc = arcpy.Describe(in_raster)
    lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(ras_desc.extent.XMin,ras_desc.extent.YMin)
    cellSize_res = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(in_raster, "CELLSIZEX")
    cellSize = cellSize_res.getOutput(0)
    spatialref = ras_desc.spatialReference

    # Convert raster to numpy array
    array_inras = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(in_raster,lowerLeft,nodata_to_value=0)

    # Perform normal score transformation calculation on numpy array based on van der Waerden's method (Conover, 1999)
    array_norm = norm.ppf(rankdata(array_inras).reshape(array_inras.shape)/(len(array_inras) + 1))

    # Convert transformed array back to raster
    norm_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(array_norm, lowerLeft, float(cellSize), value_to_nodata=0)

    # Save raster
    norm_raster.save("mypath" + str(name) + "_n")
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(norm_raster, spatialref)
```

Upon running this script, it will either fail on the line where the normal score transformation is performed with no arcpy error specified on the traceback, or result in an outputted raster that only makes up a small portion of the input raster extent.

Example:

Output raster extent (red) overlying the input raster.

[image: Input and Output rasters]

The input rasters are single band, 32 bit floating point type.

I have tried running it with various different raster datasets and I can't identify a reason that might cause it to fail versus run with a smaller extent output. I am fairly new to python so I'm not sure if there is some issue in my code that is causing this issue or if it's an issue with the method.

Edit:
This is the traceback I get. Looks like it is causing a memory error.

```
PYTHON ERRORS:
PYTHON ERRORS:
Traceback info:
  File "mypath\NormalScoreTransformation.py", line 36, in <module>
    array_norm = norm.ppf(rankdata(array_inras).reshape(array_inras.shape)/(len(array_inras) + 1))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1840, in ppf
    place(output, cond2, argsreduce(cond2, lower_bound)[0])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 546, in argsreduce
    return [np.extract(cond, arr1 * expand_arr) for arr1 in newargs]
MemoryError
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Updated the post to include the traceback. Unfortunately it doesn't give any specific errors.

Comment: That doesn't look like a typical Python traceback, are you using some extra error handling code that you haven't posted?  If so I'd try removing that to get some more detail out of the error

Comment: Ah ok, reran it without the other code and updated the post with the more detailed traceback. Looks like it fails as a result of a memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was changing my method to use a Box-Cox power transform to approximate normality. More information on that method can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html).

To implement this change I replaced the perform normal score transformation line with this code.

```
# Perform Power transformation calculation on numpy array based on the Box-Cox method
array_flat = array_inras.flatten()
array_nonzero = array_flat + 0.01
array_bc, lam = stats.boxcox(array_nonzero)
array_norm = array_bc.reshape(array_inras.shape)
```